# Individually Border a Single Column in Power BI

Tags: formatting, border, powerbi

I am looking to border a single column of a table in PBI.  I can border the entire table, and I can border just the headers, but how does one create a border formatted to a specific column?

Comment: spoof it with an image.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot format a single column. However, one workaround would be to use a rectangular shape around the column. Then, Go to the Format option and put the shape 'behind' the table. Or you can bring the Table 'in front' of the shape.